# Let p and q are odd prime numbers such that q=2p+1.

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory

Let p and q are odd prime numbers such that q=2p+1. Prove that

i) $-4$ is primitive root modulo $q$.

ii) If $p  \equiv  1 \pmod 4$ then $2$ is a primitive root mod $q$.

iii) If $p  \equiv  -1 \pmod 4$ then $-2$ is a primitive root mod $q$.

Comment: welcome to MSE, 1. This site uses [Mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-qu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bick-reference) for typing the questions. 2.  Please have a look on  ["How to ask a good question"](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)  3. Don't forget to add your own attempts and at which part you got stuck, so that others can help you.

Comment: @Lulu: yes it is a duplicate. An with two very good answers.

Comment: I searched, but i can't find this. Thank you. :) :)